# mvn clean install not working

Tags: java, maven, heroku, java-9

```
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)

        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:5
1)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContai
ner.java:263)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContai
ner.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfigu
redMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:519)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Nativ
e Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Native
MethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(De
legatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.<clinit>(Abstrac
tZipArchiver.java:116)
        ... 88 more
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.jar.JarMojo
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInsta
nce0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInsta
nce(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newI
nstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:
488)
        at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInsta
nce(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:86)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorI
njector.java:105)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(Constructor
Injector.java:32)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInje
ctor.java:89)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.p
rovision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.p
rovision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(P
rovisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorI
njector.java:87)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(Constru
ctorBindingImpl.java:267)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:10
16)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.ja
va:1103)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)

        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java
:1051)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClas
s.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(Provider
InternalFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.prov
ision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInt
ernalFactory.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.p
rovision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.p
rovision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(P
rovisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(Provid
erInternalFactory.java:63)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(
InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:10
16)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.ja
va:1103)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)

        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)

        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:5
1)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusRequirements$RequirementProvider.get(Pl
exusRequirements.java:250)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(Provid
edPropertyBinding.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52
)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersI
njectorImpl.java:140)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorI
njector.java:114)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(Constructor
Injector.java:32)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInje
ctor.java:89)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.p
rovision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.p
rovision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(P
rovisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorI
njector.java:87)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(Constru
ctorBindingImpl.java:267)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:10
16)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.ja
va:1103)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)

        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java
:1051)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClas
s.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(Provider
InternalFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.prov
ision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInt
ernalFactory.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.p
rovision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.p
rovision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(P
rovisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(Provid
erInternalFactory.java:63)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(
InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:10
16)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.ja
va:1092)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)

        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)

        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:5
1)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContai
ner.java:263)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContai
ner.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfigu
redMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:519)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Nativ
e Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Native
MethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(De
legatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.<clinit>(Abstrac
tZipArchiver.java:116)
        ... 88 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.688 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-01T07:43:16-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/97M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar
 (default-jar) on project java-getting-started: Execution default-jar of goal or
g.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar failed: An API incompatibility w
as encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar
: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/m
aven-jar-plugin/2.6/maven-jar-plugin-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.5.
6/slf4j-jdk14-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1
.5.6/jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting
/maven-reporting-api/2.2.1/maven-reporting-api-2.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/dox
ia-sink-api/1.1/doxia-sink-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/dox
ia-logging-api/1.1/doxia-logging-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.
8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.
2/commons-cli-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus
-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/b
ackport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexu
s-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexu
s-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexu
s-interpolation/1.11/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-ar
chiver/2.6/maven-archiver-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/m
aven-shared-utils/0.7/maven-shared-utils-0.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/
jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexu
s-utils/3.0.20/plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexu
s-archiver/2.9/plexus-archiver-2.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexu
s-io/2.4/plexus-io-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.2
/commons-io-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/Umair/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/common
s-compress/1.9/commons-compress-1.9.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContaine
rException
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have been following heroku tutorial for java https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#declare-app-dependencies. I installed java 9 and maven 3.5.0. Now I am getting this error. kindly help. I saw many solutions but none of those worked for me. I also tried deleting m2.repository as it was a common solution in many posts but it didn't work.

Comment: Please share the `<build>` details of your pom.xml that you are using. And also what command are you using to execute the build? On a side note, pasting the entire build logs doesn't seem relevant, do some debugging and share the relevant part with the community.

Comment: From what I can tell, the plexus-archiver was updated a long time ago to support JDK 9 (https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-archiver/pull/12). I see several plugins ran into this so they updated their dependences to use a new version.

Comment: @AlanBateman Correct. It is necessary to use the most recent version of the plugins which contains the correct updates for example for plexus-archiver etc. For example maven-jar-plugin is already there in 3.0.2 which contains that already...Apart from that failing Zip file looks like an issue with the downloaded artifact (sometimes happen based on firewall/proxy issues)...Furthermore testing on command is the best to start with...

Comment: I installed java 8 and it's working now. Thanks

Comment: Off-Topic :: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: What is your point?

Comment: @user6040594 What I am trying to say is that the problem was solved in a way that it is unlikely to help future readers. You tried java 8 then installed java 9 and then went back to java 8. It would have been great if it was fixed in Java 9 once you planned to migrate to it.

Comment: I found eventually looking at the source code that the problem is caused by java.version format, that was x.y.z up to certain version when it changed to just a number. The program is splitting by dot and trying to get the second number. This gives the exception mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update the maven-jar-plugin to the latest, such as(Date: 2017-10-02):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, and updating my maven-assembly-plugin fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The log line

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.(AbstractZipArchiver.java:116)

leads me to the assumption that one of the jars in your project is damaged. This happens sometimes when a download initiated by maven fails. It's impossible to which one is damaged because your log is incomplete.

You should try

```
mvn clean install -U
```

which will force an update of all snapshots.

If this doesn't work examine your maven repository. A quick but rather ineffective way would be to remove your local repository.

Comment: An `-U` does not help for releases. Best is to delete the local repo...

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause being this line in

```
org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.9.1/plexus-archiver-2.9.1.jar

plexus-archiver/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/archiver/zip
/AbstractZipArchiver.java

private static final boolean isJava7OrLower = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("java.version").split("\\.")[1]) <= 7;
```

Which throws

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.<clinit> (AbstractZipArchiver.java:116)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller (Constructor.java:500)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:481)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$ReflectiveProxy.newInstance (DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision (ConstructorInjector.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000 (ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call (ConstructorInjector.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct (ConstructorInjector.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:243)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.manager.DefaultArchiverManager.getArchiver (DefaultArchiverManager.java:63)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchiver (DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:302)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive (DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute (AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:484)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:299)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:963)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:296)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:199)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
```

For certain jdks, java.version=15, but for old versions, like jdk8, it works, since java.version=1.8.0_381, so the split brings 3 tokens {1,8,0_381}.

So changing the JDK can help in this case...

**Example**

You can test the **JDK compatibility** with **Plexus-archiver-2.9.1** by doing this simple test:

```
public class A {
 public static void main (String[] args) {
  System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
  int i = 
  Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("java.version").split("\\.")[1]);
  boolean b = i <= 7;
  System.out.println(b);
 }
}
```

Here is the result for JDK 11 and JDK 15

- Working with JDK 11

D:>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\javac" A.java
D:>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java" A

11.0.20

true

- Not Working with JDK 15

D:>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin\javac" A.java

D:>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin\java" A

15

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
at A.main(A.java:4)**

- It is possible to compile with JDK 15 BUT execute with Java 11

D:\sources\en.SWP_Scrum\en.SWP_Scrum>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin\javac" --source 11 --target 11 A.java
warning: [options] system modules path not set in conjunction with -source 11
1 warning

D:\sources\en.SWP_Scrum\en.SWP_Scrum>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java" A`

11.0.20

true